# Python integer division operator vs math.floor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any benefit in performance using integer division operator over math.floor?

```
7 // 2
```

over

```
math.floor(7/2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Integer division is much faster than a `math.floor` function call:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('7//2')
0.024671780910702337
>>> timeit.timeit('floor(7/2)', setup='from math import floor')
0.27053647879827736
>>> timeit.timeit('math.floor(7/2)', setup='import math')
0.3131167508719699
```

As you can see with this disassembly, using the `math` module's `floor` function (with `import math` and `math.floor` or `from math import floor` and `floor`) involve extra lookups and function calls over the plain integer division:

```
>>> import dis
>>> import math
>>> from math import floor
>>> def integer_division():
...     7//2
...
>>> def math_floor():
...     floor(7/2)
...
>>> def math_full_floor():
...     math.floor(7/2)
...
>>> dis.dis(integer_division)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              3 POP_TOP
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(math_floor)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (floor)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (3.5)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(math_full_floor)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (math)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (floor)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3.5)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Your comparison isn't particularly meaningful, because as you can see the Python compiler has replaced any actual division logic by a precomputed constant. Consider using function arguments as dividend and divisor. Also, the disassembly doesn't tell anything about the runtimes of the VM commands.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, there's some overhead in a function call, and if you do this enough times, you see a difference in speed:

```
Run time for //: 12.940021991729736 sec
Run time for floor: 26.933987855911255 sec
```

Here's the code I ran:

```
from time import time
from math import floor

start_time = time()
for i in range(1, 10000):
    for j in range(1, 10000):
        result = i // j
print('Run time for //:', time() - start_time, 'sec')

start_time = time()
for i in range(1, 10000):
    for j in range(1, 10000):
        result = floor(i/j)
print('Run time for floor:', time() - start_time, 'sec')
```