Implementation difference between math.floor and // in python
Can someone shed clarity on the difference between the math.floor() function and // operator. From what I read they practically do the same thing. But I tried some stuff and they actually seem to have different outputs sometimes. Attached to this message is an example where they output different result
def try_floor():
 return math.floor(47642706656219667964201 / 2)


def try_double_backslash():
 return 47642706656219667964201 // 2


These are the results respectively
23821353328109835780096

23821353328109833982100


One does integer math, the other floating point math that has limited precision.

When your numbers get big, float is not that accurate. For example, if you try
a=9007199254740992.0; print (a== a+1) you'll find that it prints True

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777772/python-integer-division-operator-vs-math-floor

Sorry for that, I'm not really use to stackoverflow. Thanks for the correction though. Edited the question.

@tripleee it isn’t a possible duplicate, it is a duplicate. The answer over there actually solves this.

@ChukwujiobiCanon why do you say it's a duplicate? That question focuses on performance between those two. I want to know the exact reason those two output different results. Maybe I'm the one not understanding. Can you please enlighten me. Thanks

Performance doesn't matter here. There are roughly equivalent unless the integers x or y are truly huge, in which case x / y is probably going to be too wrong to use, no matter how fast you can compute it.

You should actually think about the difference between / and // operators. The floor part is less important here.
The regular division operator has floating-point result. The precision of floating-point numbers is limited; they can't represent any number exactly. Even if the result is a whole number, if it's very big, it will be "truncated" to floating-point precision. People usually ignore this, because floating-point precision is usually good enough for real-life measurements. However, in this case, this is what's going on.
Floating-point numbers have precision of about 16 decimal digits. If you want exact integer calculations, use integer division: integers don't have any limitation on number of digits, and all integers can be represented exactly. This is what's going on in the example with // operator.
